# Running polymer serve to serve publically in a virtual machine (VM)

Tags: vagrant, polymer, virtual-machine

Using the Polymer CLI, can `polymer serve` be used to run the web server publicly so the computer hosting the VM can see the site? i.e. hosting it like a normal webserver?

To place this in context, I'd like to use Polymer CLI in a Vagrant created VM and run `polymer serve` in the virtual machine to see the results and isolate the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started trying polymer this morning and ran across the same problem/question as i didnt want to try on my host machine.

Here is what i did:

1. sudo a2enmod proxy_http
2. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

added to vhost-entry:

```
ProxyPass /polymer/ http://localhost:8080/

ProxyPassReverse /polymer/ http://localhost:8080/
```

3. sudo service apache2 restart

Please dont kill me guys, if its stupid, but it seems to work so far.

Comment: Nice solution and it works well! Note for anyone new to `ProxyPass`, `/polymer/` is the path `http://localhost:8080/` will be served from. So if you're working on a component then the url would be `yourvagrantdomain/polymer/components/yourcomponentname`. This answer requires Apache too if your not familiar with this. Thanks Mugen